# rails 3 form_for doesn't output anything

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for

Hi I have any form with nested form, for example

```
<% form_for :main do |f| %>
  trying to insert code here
  <% fields_for :nested do |nested_form| %>
    <%= nested_form.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And then I am trying to insert anything to a main form, nested form doesn't produce any output. It outputs only when it is the only object in main form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [Rails 3 documentation examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) you need to write your form_for like this:

```
<%= form_for :main do |f| %>
  # trying to insert code here
   <%= fields_for :nested do |nested_form| %>
    <%= nested_form.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note the **<%=** for both form_for and fields_for

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking to those examples but missed that ^^

Comment: I bet, since it has changed, it's confused a bunch of people!

Comment: I believe it should still output the form, but gives a warning in the console saying it's deprecated without the '='.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue in Rails 3.2. No warning.